# Using BETWEEN in CASE SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the avarage rate for all 12 months from our rate table and divide it by months, i started writing an SQL select with case, but i seem to be doing something wrong in the "Between" part..here's my SQL

```
SELECT AVG(SELL_RATE),
       AVG(BUY_RATE),
       CASE MONTHS
            WHEN RATE_DATE( BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31') THEN 'JANUARY'
            ELSE 'NOTHING'
   END AS 'MONTHS'
FROM   RATE
WHERE  CURRENCY_ID = CURRENCY -033'
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Take out the MONTHS from your case, and remove the brackets... like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN RATE_DATE BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31' THEN 'JANUARY'
    ELSE 'NOTHING'
END AS 'MONTHS'
```

You can think of this as being equivalent to:

```
CASE TRUE
    WHEN RATE_DATE BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31' THEN 'JANUARY'
    ELSE 'NOTHING'
END AS 'MONTHS'
```

Comment: How to use between for integer range

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify why you think it is wrong but I can se two dangers:

BETWEEN can be implemented differently in different databases sometimes it is including the border values and sometimes excluding, resulting in that 1 and 31 of january would end up NOTHING. You should test how you database does this.

Also, if RATE_DATE contains hours also 2010-01-31 might be translated to 2010-01-31 00:00 which also would exclude any row with an hour other that 00:00.

Comment: sorry i am using MS SQL 2005,,the issue with the query is that it does not return any results, do you see anything wrong with it? SELECT AVG(cr.SELL_TRANSFER) AS SELL,
   
       CASE   WHEN   cr.RATE_DATE BETWEEN '02-10-2008' AND '30-10-2008' THEN 'JANUARY'
   END AS 'MONTH'
   FROM   CURRENCY_RATE cr
WHERE  cr.CURRENCY_ID = 'CURRENCY -033'
GROUP BY CR.RATE_DATE

Comment: Start by chsing the query to SELECT * FROM and work on getting any rows back, that way you can concentrate on the where part and go for the select when you have some data. If you still cannot gen any results please include a few rows from the table that you think should match so that we can test this.